# Export messages from the ActiveMQ Artemis dead letter queue and reimport them on another cluster

Tags: debugging, jms, activemq-artemis

I would like to export failed messages from an ActiveMQ Artemis dead letter queue and re-import them on another cluster to debug the processing. The functionality of the Artemis CLI does not seem to support anything like that? Has somebody an idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `message transfer` command to consume messages from a JMS queue on one broker and send them to a JMS queue on another broker, e.g.:

```
$ ./artemis message transfer --source-url tcp://broker1:61616 --source-queue DLQ --target-url tcp://broker2:61616 --target-queue myQueue
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?